# Unable to install SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) on server

Tags: ssms, installation, errors

We are experiencing persistent errors when attempting to install SSMS on one of our development database servers. We have tried the installers for versions 17.4 and 17.9.1, but the error messages are the same.

**Extracts from SSMS-Setup-ENU_20190319131949.log (17.4)**

```
10C0:10B8][2019-03-19T13:28:23]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 50, Overall progress: 65
[1E58:1E70][2019-03-19T13:28:24]e000: Error 0x80070643: Process returned error: 0x643
[1E58:1E70][2019-03-19T13:28:24]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute EXE package.
[10C0:10B8][2019-03-19T13:28:24]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[10C0:10B8][2019-03-19T13:28:24]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Completed for package Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015 Language Support
...
[10C0:10B8][2019-03-19T13:33:28]e000: MainViewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action failed: Fatal error during installation (0x80070643)
[10C0:10B8][2019-03-19T13:33:28]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[10C0:1C40][2019-03-19T13:33:42]i000: MainViewModel.OpenUrl: Opening url: C:\Users\******~1\AppData\Local\Temp\SsmsSetup\SSMS-Setup-ENU_20190319131949.log
```

**Extracts from SSMS-Setup-ENU_20190319134134.log (17.9.1)**

```
[16C4:2298][2019-03-19T13:49:35]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 50, Overall progress: 67
[2324:1D80][2019-03-19T13:49:35]e000: Error 0x80070643: Process returned error: 0x643
[2324:1D80][2019-03-19T13:49:35]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute EXE package.
[16C4:2298][2019-03-19T13:49:35]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[16C4:2298][2019-03-19T13:49:35]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Completed for package Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015 Language Support
[16C4:2298][2019-03-19T13:49:35]i319: Applied execute package: VSTALS2015, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
[16C4:2298][2019-03-19T13:49:35]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute EXE package.
[2324:1D80][2019-03-19T13:49:35]i351: Removing cached package: VS2015KB3095681Update, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\02A26E554FBB4232ACD36E70D09F2C7893D399CD\
...
[16C4:2298][2019-03-19T13:55:14]e000: MainViewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action failed: Fatal error during installation (0x80070643)
[16C4:2298][2019-03-19T13:55:14]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[16C4:1798][2019-03-19T13:56:28]i000: MainViewModel.OpenUrl: Opening url: C:\Users\******~1\AppData\Local\Temp\SsmsSetup\SSMS-Setup-ENU_20190319134134.log
```

[image]

The installer takes many minutes to arrive at this point, but fails with the same result each time.

We have restarted the server in between each attempt, and have run on the latest Windows Updates. We have .NET Framework 4.5.2 installed on the server. All attempts have been made using accounts with full admin permissions on the server.

Can anyone please advise how we can get this installed successfully?

Comment: Have a look at this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/895abf27-0e81-4fec-a692-9d93386f7af5/unable-to-install-sql-server-management-studio-2017-v177-fatal-error-0x80070643?forum=sqltools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per MSDN BOL documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)  for the SSMS 17.9.1 installation the **`.NET Framework`** should be **`4.6.1`** (or **`greater`**).

Make sure you are running an up-to-date version of the Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable Package. Version 12.0.40649.5 (or greater) is required. Only the x64 version is needed. And also all the latest OS updates are installed on the computer.

For further your ref [here](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/fix-error-0x80070643-on-windows/)

Comment: Thank you, we had done most of these - in the end, we had to go through all of the following prerequisites:

.Net 4.6.1 or greater
Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable package or greater (only x64 bit required)
Latest Windows Updates installed
Restart required before proceeding

Remove the \users\current user\appdata\temp\ssmssetup folder (containing the failed log files)
Undomain the server (requires a restart)

Run the installation with elevated permissions